# Getting an error in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am just getting started with using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I am using SQL Server 2014 with this. I am following a tutorial on YouTube so that I can learn how to create a database with this software.

However, I get an error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Invalid object name 'temp'.

Here is my list of commands so far. Everything executed until the 3rd line:

```
create database youtube

create table temp(id int, name varchar(20))

insert into temp 
values (1, 'hello'), (2, 'Abc'), (3, 'John'), (4, 'Harry'), 
       (5, 'Shaun'), (6, 'Mike')
```

If it helps with figuring out the problem, I did leave this thing alone for about 30 minutes or so to go have lunch, and when I came back I was disconnected from the server. I reconnected to the server, and that's when the problem started coming up.

I also have the link to the YouTube video right here so you can see where I got this from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Vv7qYhEixo

Comment: You most likely aren't connected to the database in your query window. Look in the top left of SSMS. In the video you'll see it says `youTube`. Your's probably says `master` so you are trying to query `temp` in the `master` database instead of `youTube`. Change it there.

Comment: Forgot about that. Thanks! Tried that and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @scsimon, you can change your active database in the SSMS window.

You can also use the `USE` command to change your active database: `use youtube`.

Finally, it's a good idea to commit each step of your DDL (database creation, table creation, etc.). For example:

```
create database youtube
go

use youtube
go

create table temp(id int, name varchar(20))
go

insert into temp 
values (1, 'hello'), (2, 'Abc'), (3, 'John'), (4, 'Harry'), 
       (5, 'Shaun'), (6, 'Mike')
```